# How to add metadata (from a separate file) to Author pages in Pelican blogs?

Tags: pelican

I'm working on including data from a separate metadata file, to be displayed on Author pages.

Each author has a separate metadata file.

For example, each author has a 'ranking' variable with a value for that author (such as 'Beginner', 'Intermediate', or 'Advanced').

That 'ranking' variable would need to be accessible to the template, so that the template could display the 'ranking' value as part of the page, showing the ranking for that specific author whose page is being viewed.

I've tried creating a plugin and attempted to access the various signals as listed on [the Plugins page](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/plugins.html) of the Pelican documentation, but after several hours (over a day of [looking at tutorials](http://adamcot.com/posts/2018/02/building-pelican-plugins-i/) and the source code, actually), nothing has worked.

Since this seems like it should be simple, though the documentation really isn't helpful at all, I wondered if anyone else had successfully done this before, or knows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered this one in about ten minutes by adapting [the Author Images plugin](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/blob/master/author_images) from the [Pelican plugins Github repo](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins).

Works perfectly now. :)